# Why do I see 404 http errors for requests with an agent called "VMRuntimeHealthChecker/1.0"?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am testing a server on GAE, and the experience has been smooth. I wanted to see how fast I could POST and GET from the server and at around 10 requests/second, but I noticed that some of the requests in my logs were http 404 errors and the agent was a string I didn't recognize called "VMRuntimeHealthChecker/1.0". I am assuming this is some google service interacting with my server, but am not sure.

I also see another request sometimes showing 404 error, which had the agent "curl/7.26.0". Again, not an agent I recognize. It may be related, but I am not sure. (To be clear: As part of my test, I did not make any requests via curl)

Does anyone know what these requests could represent? I did not see this behaviour on heroku when I tested the same backend on there.

Comment: I'm seeing these logs as well. We're using Flexible Environment with `python` runtime and using Gunicorn. It's creating a lot of noise for our logs.